# GitHub: Different Repo(remote) for different SubDirectory

Tags: git, github

I am new to Git Hub and had a query regarding the same.

I have a main directory named Base and 3 sub directories named src, config and licence(sample names).

for the same i have created 3 Repositories. with the same name.

What i want to know is that how can i run `git init` on just the Base Directory and link the sub directories to their respective repositories(remotes).

please suggest if this is possible or should i run `git init` on 3 different directories and add 1 remote to each of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) which will allow you to do this.